# How can I test if a variable is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is the pseudo-code of what I want to do:

```
if @current_user is defined then puts @current_user.name
```

Comment: I am surprised by your choice of best answer, and suspect @Jörg may be as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you *really* need to know whether the variable is defined or is it enough to know whether it contains a valid `User` object?

Instance variables will never raise a `NameError`, even when they are not defined. They just evaluate to `nil`, so you can just check for that:

```
puts @current_user.name unless @current_user.nil?
```

Since your question is tagged [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), I'll assume that you have `ActiveSupport` loaded anyway, so you can also use the `Object#try` extension method:

```
puts @current_user.try(:name)
```

Comment: **In addition:** the `.try(:method)` can be interesting here: `@current_user.try(:name)`

Comment: Yep, if you're using ActiveSupport anyway (the question is tagged [tag:ruby-on-rails], after all), that's also a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

Use the operator [`defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F) then.

```
x = 10
defined? x # => "local-variable"
defined? y # => nil
@x = 10
defined? @x # => "instance-variable"
!!defined? x # => true
!!defined? y # => false
```

write your code as below:

```
puts @current_user.name if !!defined?(@current_user)
```

Comment: Nitpick: `defined?` is not a method, it's special unary prefix operator. It *can't* be a method, because methods evaluate their arguments before they are executed, and thus your third line would raise a `NameError` if `defined?` were a method (or even a normal operator). It's just *documented* as a method, because, well, there's no other way to document it in RDoc.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks for letting me know this..But it is documented in the Object class as a method.. why so?

Comment: Because RDoc only supports documentation of things you can write yourself (modules, classes, methods, variables), not things that only the language designers can create (keywords, magic special operators). In particular, `defined?` is really the *only* operator of its kind, so it just doesn't make sense to add support to RDoc for documenting something which a) nobody can write and b) where only one instance of it exists.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I am now confused how I write my answer.. Can I put your comments as a quote? please allow me

Comment: Just replace "method" with "operator" :-)

Comment: Put another way: RDoc is for documenting code *written in Ruby*, not for documenting *Ruby language constructs*. But still people want to have all the documentation for Ruby in one place, and thus, they try to "abuse" RDoc.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I wouldn't mind if you write those valuable information in my answer itself also.. As you are always in my favorite [answerers list...](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2767755/arup-rakshit) :)

Comment: That might actually be a good SO question on its own. Just ask it, and I'll answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
puts @current_user.name if instance_variable_defined?(:@current_user)
```